# how to throw an exception from php to angular $http service

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

i am working on a blog in angularJS and i use php to generate a json with data from a database.
My angular 'get article' function looks like this

```
$scope.getDetail = function() {
        $http.get('php/blogGetArticle.php?id=2').success(function(json) {
            $scope.jsonDetail = json;
            alert('ok');
        }).error(function() {
            alert('error');
        });
    };
```

and my php 'blogGetArticle.php' looks like this.

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbport = "5432";
    $dbname = "pd";
    $dbuser = "postgres";
    $dbpass = "123";
    $connect = pg_connect("host=" . $dbhost . " port=" . $dbport . " dbname=" . $dbname . " user=" . $dbuser . " password=" . $dbpass);
    if(!$connect)
        die("error 0"); // connect error

    $query = "SELECT * FROM blog WHERE id=" . $id;
    $result = pg_query($connect, $query);
    if(!$result)
        die('error 1'); // query error

    $row = pg_fetch_row($result);
    $json = '{';
    $json .= '"id":"' . addslashes($row[0]) . '",';
    $json .= '"title":"' . addslashes($row[1]) . '",';
    $json .= '"message":"' . addslashes($row[2]) . '",';
    $json .= '"category":"' . addslashes($row[4]) . '"';
    $json .= '}';

    echo $json;
?>
```

Now what i try to do is i try to make the angular function take to the .error branch when i call something inside php .. i dont know how to explain well. Example when i have in php an id that is lower than 10, i want the angular function to throw an exception but i want to make it from php file to throw that exception to angular function.

Thank you, Daniel!

EDIT: so how do i throw a 4xx or 5xx error ?

Comment: I don't know about PHP, but if you return HTTP response codes 4xx or 5xx depending on the situation, those confirm to HTTP errors.

Answer (score 3):

PHP:

```
try {
} catch (Exception $e) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
    echo '{"data": "Exception occurred: '.$e->getMessage().'"}';
}
```

AngularJS

```
        , function(error) {
          $log.error('Error message: '+error.data);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like

```
  if(!$connect)
      // or may be code 500
       header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
       exit; 

$query = "SELECT * FROM blog WHERE id=" . $id;
$result = pg_query($connect, $query);
if(!$result)
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    exit;
```

I advice you to try http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php without any further ado :)

Bye

Answer (score -2):

Couldn't you return json with a different format?

```
if(!$result){
    $json = '{';
    $json .= '"error":"failed loading data",';
    $json .= '}';
}else{
    $row = pg_fetch_row($result);
    $json = '{';
    $json .= '"id":"' . addslashes($row[0]) . '",';
    $json .= '"title":"' . addslashes($row[1]) . '",';
    $json .= '"message":"' . addslashes($row[2]) . '",';
    $json .= '"category":"' . addslashes($row[4]) . '"';
    $json .= '}';
}
echo $json;
```

Then in angular detect if error exists in json and then you can plan for multiple errors vs processes status result calls.

```
jsonObj.hasOwnProperty("error")
```

Comment: Thats not a right way. If you want to return error for HTTP call, one needs to send 4xx or 5xx response code.

Comment: Depends on the purpose, not sure what the OP is trying to accomplish. Its good to point out the more standard approach though, thank you.

Comment: Non standart approaches can cause bad things, like php.

Comment: and so can standard approaches... thankfully that is why we have the creative job to review and figure out what works best for any given situation.

Comment: what i am trying to achieve is for example if a person requests a post with an id that i dont have it on database.. what error should i return ?